# Finding values in a string:string dictionary where a given filter string is a subset of the key string

Tags: c#, dictionary, filter

I have a `Dictionary<string, string>` object where values are stored that look like this:

```
examplePlanet                   : defaultText0
examplePlanet*                  : defaultText1
examplePlanet**                 : defaultText2
examplePlanetSpecificlocationA  : specificAText0
examplePlanetSpecificlocationA* : specificAText1
examplePlanetSpecificlocationB  : specificBText
```

And I have a string `filter` that matches one of these keys or is a subset of a key.
This filter has the form `planetLocation`, which can be split into `planet` and `location`.

My goal is to create a list of values where the filter is matched in this way: if planetLocation exists in the dictionary, add its value, and all values where the key matches but has extra *'s, to a list.
If planetLocation does not exist, only add values where the key matches the `planet` part of the filter (with possible extra *'s).

Basically, I want all values where the filter matches the key as much as possible.

---

Examples:

`examplePlanetSpecificlocationA` gives `[specificAText0, specificAText1]`
`examplePlanetSpecificlocationB` gives `[specificBText]`
`examplePlanetSpecificlocationC` gives `[defaultText0, defaultText1, defaultText2]`

---

I have already tried (among other things that didn't work) this:

```
private List<string> filteredResults;

///<summary>Filters dictionaries and returns a list of values</summary>
private List<string> GetFilteredResults(Dictionary<string, string> inputdictionary, string filter)
{
    List<string> _filteredResults = new List<string>();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in inputdictionary)
    {
        if (entry.Key.Contains(filter))
        {
            _filteredResults.Add(entry.Value);
        }
    }
    return _filteredResults;
}

public void main()
{
    //stuff happens here that assigns a value to filterPlanet and filterLocation

    filteredResults = new List<string>();
    filteredResults = GetFilteredResults(exampledictionary, filterPlanet + filterLocation);
    if (filteredResults.Count == 0)
    {
        filteredResults = GetFilteredResults(exampledictionary, filterPlanet);
    }

    //do stuff with the filtered results
}
```

This almost worked, but returns all values where the key contains filterPlanet and not just filterPlanet itself plus possible *'s. I'm not sure how to make this function do what I want, and even if it somehow works I'm sure there is a more efficient way of filtering than this. Could you please help me here?

Comment: Why does "examplePlanetSpecificlocationC " match "examplePlanet"? Why does "examplePlanetSpecificlocationA" match "examplePlanetSpecificlocationA*"?

Comment: @canton7 examplePlanetSpecificlocationC does not exist in the dictionary, so instead the default value(s) should be returned, which are stored in a key with the same name but without the location bit.
edit: examplePlanetSpecificlocationA always matches examplePlanetSpecificlocationA* since the first is a subset of the latter with only asterixes added. A dictionary can't have the same key twice, this seems to be a workaround for that.

Comment: Right, but "examplePlanet" doesn't end with a "*"? And why does "examplePlanetSpecificlocationA" match "examplePlanetSpecificlocationA*", if it's already got a specific match in "examplePlanetSpecificlocationA"?

Comment: It would be better if you could write out your algorithm in detail, using a multi-level list or a flow chart. Detail exactly what steps should be taken, and what should happen in *all* cases. That will help you implement it, too.

Comment: I would like to suggest that using a string dictionary is not the correct approach to solve this issue. Does it HAVE to be a string dictionary (eg. do you get this exact data from an external source) or would you be able to use a different data structure?

Comment: Using some sort of tree is probably the way to go, but it's hard to say for sure until the requirements are clear.

Comment: @Longoon12000 yes, this is a dictionary I get from a function outside of my control. I could rewrite it to a more usable format where for example the values are lists containing all variations, I'll look into that.

Comment: Then you may want to use a regular expression to apply your filter by those rules. Something along `$@"^{filter}\**$"` (match all strings that start with your filter and end in zero or many `*`). Then you just have to check if you have any results, if not find the default and return that.

Comment: @canton7 there are default values and more specific values. If the filter contains a specific value which exists in the list, return all values of which the keys are exactly that filter or with added asterixes. If the dictionary does not contain filter, return all default values for that filter (again, or with added asterixes).

Comment: Do the `*`'s add anything? Couldn't you have `examplePlanetSpecificlocationA` mapping to `[specificAText0, specificAText1]` (and not have `examplePlanetSpecificlocationA*`)?

Comment: @canton7 I could reshape the input to a Dictionary<string, List<string>>, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use the `*`'s as a way of differentiating multiple values for the same key, and I'd keep `filterPlanet` and `filterLocation` separate. That way you can use a simple O(1) dictionary lookup, rather than iterating across all keys, doing substring searching, etc.

```
public class PlanetFilterer
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, List<string>> lookup = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    public PlanetFilterer(IEnumerable<(string filter, string value)> filters)
    {
        foreach (var (filter, value) in filters)
        {
            var filterWithoutStars = filter.TrimEnd('*');
            if (!lookup.TryGetValue(filterWithoutStars, out var values))
            {
                values = new List<string>();
                lookup[filterWithoutStars] = values;
            }
            values.Add(value);
        }
    }

    public IReadOnlyList<string> Lookup(string planet, string location)
    {
        List<string> results;
        if (lookup.TryGetValue(planet + location, out results))
        {
            return results; 
        }
        if (lookup.TryGetValue(planet, out results))
        {
            return results;
        }
        return Array.Empty<string>();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var filters = new[]
{
    ("examplePlanet", "defaultText0"),
    ("examplePlanet*", "defaultText1"),
    ("examplePlanet**", "defaultText2"),
    ("examplePlanetSpecificlocationA", "specificAText0"),
    ("examplePlanetSpecificlocationA*", "specificAText1"),
    ("examplePlanetSpecificlocationB", "specificBText"),
};
var filterer = new PlanetFilterer(filters);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", filterer.Lookup("examplePlanet", "SpecificlocationA")));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", filterer.Lookup("examplePlanet", "SpecificlocationB")));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", filterer.Lookup("examplePlanet", "SpecificlocationC")));
```

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/III0fC)

Comment: I unfortunately can't control the input, I can only reshape it. The .TrimEnd is definitely something I didn't think of though, I'm sure either that or @Longoon12000 's regex will work.

Comment: @asdfCYBER Notice how my code takes input in the same format as in your question, then processes it. The input is taken exactly from your question, and the output matches that in your question. If this isn't good enough, please expand on *why*. You've already said "*I could reshape the input to a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, yes.*"

Comment: oops yes, I read over the interface. This should definitely work, I'll try it right now.

Comment: I ended up taking my original code and replacing ```if (entry.Key.Contains(filter))``` with ```if (entry.Key.TrimEnd('*') == filter)```. While your solution is more elegant and faster if you use it more than once, I only needed to filter once to get what I need.

Comment: @asdfCYBER I'd be nervous of `Contains` as it can match anywhere. `StartsWith` is better, but just searching for the planet without the location is much better.